# Is it required to protect API routes in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I protect an API route with middleware and only users with the admin role can access the API route, it prevents the app from retrieving data from the API when the user's role is not admin. So, the question is, is there a way to protect the API but still allow access to it by users other than admin? Or should it not be protected?

I'm using Nextjs 13 btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well it depend on your project's and business needs.
for example,if your admin panel need role-base-authentication,and some pages should show only to specific type of users, then yes, you have to use it.
although, you can check user access on client side,so that users can view the page despite their roles,but you miss server side rendering performance, that is not ideal.

for better ux,on the server side, you can check if the user has required access level for view the page,if not, redirect the unauthorized users to some other page,like 403